# npm grunt using incorrect module path

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm

I'm trying to use node.js, npm with grunt.  I downloaded node.js with npm, ran `npm install` from project directory.  It ran fine.  Then I ran `install npm -g grunt-cli`, which ended with 'Ok'.

I'm running all these with default install and behind proxy which I properly configured.

Now on trying to run `grunt` from project directory results in following error:

```
module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module '%APPDATA%\npm\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:906:3
```

Notice, it inserts `Roaming\npm` again in search path.  Is there a config setting somewhere where it gets this path?  What is causing it to append Roaming\npm to prefix path?

`npm config get prefix` : %APPDATA%\npm

`NODE_PATH` environment variable is set to %APPDATA%\npm

I also tried `npm cache clean`

Edit: I changed %APPDATA%\grunt.cmd file.  Now it gets correct path, but error still persists.  It says `%APPDATA%\node_modules\grunt-cli` can't be found, but it is there.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to a bug in `path` module.  Please see here: [grunt issue](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-cli/issues/66)